# Image Overflow set to hidden but still not working

Tags: css, image, styles, overflow, parent-child

I have an image that eventhough it has a parent set to `overflow: hidden` still overflows and creates a horizontal scroll on the page. [Shown here](https://moonface.ga/static/img/8e99817d-db23-4284-b879-f7f1e416cda3.gif)

Here is the relevant code:

```
    .section2img {
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
        height: min-content;
        position: relative;
        width: 50vw;
        right: -60%;
        top: 0;
    }

    .section2 img {
        position: relative;
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }
```

[GitRepo if needed](https://github.com/kylesloper/moonface)

Comment: Have you tried setting the `body` to `overflow-x: hidden`?

Comment: Yes both `body` and `html` are set to `overflow-x: hidden`

Comment: Can you please post a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is set the width of the img so it match with the website and then add `object-fit: cover;` to the img, what it does is to cut the part that overflows.